# Angular error: Node.replaceChild does not implement interface Node.replaceWith

Tags: angularjs

I'm receiving this error using Angular in *some* browsers, but notably *not* Chrome:

```
Node.replaceChild does not implement interface Node.replaceWith
```

I bootstrap my app manually with this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notably appears to happen when bootstrapping the app on the `document` element. Use an element further down instead:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('html'), ['myApp']);
});
```

<sub>(Thought I'd document this faux pas here for the benefit of Google.)</sub>